# url provided for must have the same domain

Tags: url, json-ld

My website is [buymobile](https://www.buymobile.com.bd/).I already implement this code, our website made by opencart cms. Many time we try this code but show below error.
domain name (All values provided for https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/ must have the same domain.)

please help me

```js
    <script type="application/ld+json"> 
    { "@context" : "http://schema.org",
    "@type" : "Organization",
    "name": "buymobile.com.bd",
    "url" : "https://buymobile.com.bd/",
    "contactPoint" : [
    { "@type" : "ContactPoint",
    "telephone" : "+880171++++++",
    "email": "info@buymobile.com.bd",
    "contactType" : "customer service",
    "contactType" : "technical support",
    "availableLanguage" : ["English","Bengali"],
    "contactOption" : [],
    "areaServed" : "Bangladesh"
    } ] } </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely this error look like (All values provided for https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/ must have the same domain.) this. Actually tried a lot to solve this error in different ways. According to the [Webmaster Central Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/4dcAE5j62Bo) this actually a bug of structure data testing tool.It's not an error you can go for it.